# Set related question for two questions

Tags: support, related-questions

Can someone set a relation between those two questions:

[Minted caching in tikz externalize job](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/239780/minted-caching-in-tikz-externalize-job)

[Problem, when loading minted after \tikzexternalize](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270492/problem-when-loading-minted-after-tikzexternalize)

Or is it possible to suggest this relation within the questions directly?

Comment: Ah, I meant something similar to this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110485/equal-sign-within-tikz-label. But I think I can do this myself by using normal comments

Answer (score 4):

Any post link within the body of the post (question or answer) or in comment will be reflected in the "Linked" section of the accompanying post.

So, in order to "relate" two posts, it is typically customary to add a comment in either post with the corresponding target post link. This can be achieved by any user having the [Comment Anywhere privilege](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) (at least 50 reputation).